# error: cannot find symbol import com.example.databinding2.databinding.ActivityMainBindingImpl;

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm, 2-way-object-databinding, cannot-find-symbol

I'm unable to resolve this error.

I wanted to use two-way databinding in edittext.
Here is the code for the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="mainViewModel"
        type="com.example.databinding2.MainViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--        for two way data biding-->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@={mainViewModel.quoteLiveData}"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quoteText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{mainViewModel.quoteLiveData}"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{()-> mainViewModel.updateQuote()}"
        android:text="Update"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

for main activity

```
    package com.example.databinding2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.databinding2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        //without using dataBinding.

//        mainViewModel.quoteLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
//            binding.quoteText.text = it
//        })

//        binding.btnUpdate.setOnClickListener {
//            mainViewModel.updateQuote()
//        }

        //after dataBinding.

        binding.mainViewModel = mainViewModel //we have to pass the reference of MainViewModel to mainViewModel in UI component when we are dealing with ViewModel.
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this //for using livedata in dataBinding we have to pass lifecycle owner since livedata is lifecycle aware.

    }
}
```

for MainViewModel:

```
    package com.example.databinding2

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel


class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val quoteMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData("What you give is what you get.")

    val quoteLiveData: LiveData<String>
        get() = quoteMutableLiveData

    fun updateQuote(){
        quoteMutableLiveData.value = "You'll see it when you believe it."
    }

}
```

build gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.databinding2'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.databinding2"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1' // for ViewModel

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1' // for LiveData
}
```

error generating file: DataBinderMapperImpl.java

```
package com.example.databinding2;

import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent;
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import com.example.databinding2.databinding.ActivityMainBindingImpl;
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.RuntimeException;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class DataBinderMapperImpl extends DataBinderMapper {
  private static final int LAYOUT_ACTIVITYMAIN = 1;

  private static final SparseIntArray INTERNAL_LAYOUT_ID_LOOKUP = new SparseIntArray(1);

  static {
    INTERNAL_LAYOUT_ID_LOOKUP.put(com.example.databinding2.R.layout.activity_main, LAYOUT_ACTIVITYMAIN);
  }

  @Override
  public ViewDataBinding getDataBinder(DataBindingComponent component, View view, int layoutId) {
    int localizedLayoutId = INTERNAL_LAYOUT_ID_LOOKUP.get(layoutId);
    if(localizedLayoutId > 0) {
      final Object tag = view.getTag();
      if(tag == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("view must have a tag");
      }
      switch(localizedLayoutId) {
        case  LAYOUT_ACTIVITYMAIN: {
          if ("layout/activity_main_0".equals(tag)) {
            return new ActivityMainBindingImpl(component, view);
          }
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("The tag for activity_main is invalid. Received: " + tag);
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public ViewDataBinding getDataBinder(DataBindingComponent component, View[] views, int layoutId) {
    if(views == null || views.length == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    int localizedLayoutId = INTERNAL_LAYOUT_ID_LOOKUP.get(layoutId);
    if(localizedLayoutId > 0) {
      final Object tag = views[0].getTag();
      if(tag == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("view must have a tag");
      }
      switch(localizedLayoutId) {
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getLayoutId(String tag) {
    if (tag == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    Integer tmpVal = InnerLayoutIdLookup.sKeys.get(tag);
    return tmpVal == null ? 0 : tmpVal;
  }

  @Override
  public String convertBrIdToString(int localId) {
    String tmpVal = InnerBrLookup.sKeys.get(localId);
    return tmpVal;
  }

  @Override
  public List<DataBinderMapper> collectDependencies() {
    ArrayList<DataBinderMapper> result = new ArrayList<DataBinderMapper>(1);
    result.add(new androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.DataBinderMapperImpl());
    return result;
  }

  private static class InnerBrLookup {
    static final SparseArray<String> sKeys = new SparseArray<String>(1);

    static {
      sKeys.put(0, "_all");
    }
  }

  private static class InnerLayoutIdLookup {
    static final HashMap<String, Integer> sKeys = new HashMap<String, Integer>(1);

    static {
      sKeys.put("layout/activity_main_0", com.example.databinding2.R.layout.activity_main);
    }
  }
}
```

error messages:
[image: Error Message]
[image]

**Ignore all comments these are there because currently, I'm learning MVVM architecture.**

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the entire error message? It looks like something wrong in your `activity_main.xml`

Ensure the `mainViewModel.quoteLiveData` is MutableLiveData since you use it for two-way data bindings.

If you can share the full error message I can help you more precisely.

**Updated:**

The error is because the `quoteLiveData` is private in `MainViewModel`. Make the `quoteLiveData` public because private members cannot be accessed outside the class.

Comment: added with the question

Comment: is the `quoteLiveData` a MutableLiveData? If not please make it MutableLiveData

Comment: Make the `quoteLiveData` public. private members cannot be accessed outside the class.